# Best location for an electrical pedestal

Tags: electrical, wiring, usa

What are the variables I should be considering in this situation? What i'm trying to decide is the best location for the pedestal.

Pictured is my build site and house orientation with the attached garage at the north east square adjacent to a utility room in the garage. Obviously that pole which provides service to the lot, has to go. It is my service pole (end pole) and has a 200Amp, 240v transformer on it. Power company said they will either just move it to one of the other poles (marked on east side) or upgrade an existing transformer already on one of those poles to provide both me and the neighboring lot service. But, where I want the pedestal is up to me.

What's the best spot for the pedestal? While i'm tempted to have them put it at the pole on the fence line (and run my own wiring to the house), I'm not sure what's going to be more cost effective. Part of me thinks having it that close to the neighbors / basically in their yard is bad for security reasons? Having the pedestal where I marked it is kinda unsightly I guess but maybe best. And I'm wondering if it's cheaper for me to run my wiring from one of the poles or have the power company do it and have the pedestal near the house. What typically makes the most sense and why?

[image]

Comment: Do you control the property on both sides of the E-W fenceline?  Do you want the aesthetic of a property without pole lines?  Will all this work be hired out or DIY?

Comment: Yes - all is my property except for the right like 10% beyond the poles.

I'll DIY whatever the electric company allows. Sounds like I can DIY my trench. They put the physical wire in the ground to the pedestal and hook up the pedestal / meter.

Comment: Will the electric company let you put the pedestal there?  I thought there were placement guidelines that say that the pedestal has to be in a unobstructed line to the pole.  Or maybe that just applies to overhead wires, because you don't want the wires running over part of the structure?

Comment: @SteveSh Good question. My guess is that's just for overhead, but i'm not sure. I'll ask them to be certain, but seemed like they'd put it wherever I wanted. I'm assuming next to the house is cheapest even if I have to move it more in direct line with pole. But, maybe the question is what's cheaper: 1. Me running my own line from the ped or ped being as close as possible (power company runs lines from pole to ped)?

Comment: @maplemale -- who's your electric utility?

Comment: I would consider trenching on your property , a transformer vault  requires space around it if you have it put on your property but if you don’t want ugly wires that’s what I do I bring the feeder up and mount on the house or garage, if you put the transformer in a vault on your property normally 2 ground electrodes are needed outside the vault and a loop around the vault that ends up being the neutral. 4’ deep trench for the main feeder to the transformer , that is dictated by the power company not the NEC.  You may want to feed from a pole transformer underground Larger wire is needed here.